# Show image animation to click on Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to create an `animation` for an image. The image is placed down on a `RelativeLayout` with `-25dp margin`.

Only half of the image is displayed.

I want to **click on the red part** of the image, the **blue part image** is displayed and vice versa.

But I can not find the exact parameters for XML animations. Can anyone help me out? Thank you

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView footer;
private Animation animDown, animUp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    animDown= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_down);
    animUp= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_up);

    footer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.footer);
    footer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            footer.startAnimation(animUp);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**anim_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="750"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

**anim_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="750"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my own solution:

```
private boolean animacionUp = true;

footer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(animacionUp) {
                footer.startAnimation(animUp);
                animacionUp = false;
            } else {
                footer.startAnimation(animDown);
                animacionUp = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

**anim_down**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="-70"
    android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

**anim_up**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-70" />

</set>
```

Comment: Note that 25dp is not equal to 70px in every device! In order to have proper animation across all pixel densities, you need to calculate how many pixels are 25dp on the current device (https://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/convert-dp-to-px/) and then trigger the animation by creating a [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) in java instead of loading the animation from XML.